# ScrollView doesn't work in fragment

Tags: android, scroll, tabs, android-viewpager, swipe

Does anyone know why the scroll does not work ? I trying to make my page scrollable and can swipe to another tab. It allows me to swipe but not scrollable. I'm use most of the answer in Stack Overflow but none of them is worked in my case.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<AbsoluteLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>



    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

<TextView
        android:layout_width="353dp"
        android:layout_height="91dp"
        android:text="Use the form below to change your information or update any others of your information"
        android:id="@+id/textView16"
        android:layout_x="9dp"
        android:layout_y="57dp"
        android:textSize="20dp" />


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="186dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText9"
        android:layout_x="17dp"
        android:layout_y="146dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="143dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText12"
        android:layout_x="226dp"
        android:layout_y="146dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Information"
        android:id="@+id/textView17"
        android:layout_x="20dp"
        android:layout_y="203dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="95dp"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Weather"
        android:id="@+id/textView15"
        android:layout_x="20dp"
        android:layout_y="253dp" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="174dp"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:id="@+id/spinner5"
        android:layout_x="174dp"
        android:layout_y="238dp" />

</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Comment: What did you keep inside of LinearLayout..??

Comment: @SarithaG I'm trying to move the `pager` outside the `scrollView`

Comment: ViewPager is a separate view on the screen, and scrollView is different on the screen. You can able to scroll the view, even though View pager is there on the screen. Which type views are you adding to scrollView..??

Comment: _Which type views are you adding to scrollView??_ Sorry, I don't get what you mean

Comment: Are you using listview inside ScrollView??

Comment: @Tony there is nothing inside scrollView then what it will show.

Comment: @NigamPatro what should I put inside the scrollView?

Comment: @Tony what you want actually?

Comment: You should add some child views to linearLayout then only that scroll will work. Without adding any view, you won't get the scroll.

Comment: In this fragment, it has two tabs(A and B). I can swipe A to B now but I also want to make the A scrollable

Comment: @SarithaG did you mean I have to move all the textView to the scrollView ?

Comment: no no...wait i will post some sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add child views to linearLayout.

try something like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.samplestackoademo.MainActivity" >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <AbsoluteLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView114"
            android:layout_width="218dp"
            android:layout_height="47dp"
            android:layout_x="12dp"
            android:layout_y="20dp"
            android:text="Update Page"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView16"
            android:layout_width="353dp"
            android:layout_height="91dp"
            android:layout_x="9dp"
            android:layout_y="57dp"
            android:text="Use the form below to change your information or update any others of your information"
            android:textSize="20dp" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText9"
            android:layout_width="186dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_x="17dp"
            android:layout_y="146dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="Name" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText12"
            android:layout_width="143dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_x="226dp"
            android:layout_y="146dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView17"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_x="20dp"
            android:layout_y="203dp"
            android:text="Information"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView15"
            android:layout_width="95dp"
            android:layout_height="37dp"
            android:layout_x="20dp"
            android:layout_y="253dp"
            android:text="Weather"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner5"
            android:layout_width="174dp"
            android:layout_height="53dp"
            android:layout_x="174dp"
            android:layout_y="238dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView18"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_x="20dp"
            android:layout_y="302dp"
            android:text="Status"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner7"
            android:layout_width="174dp"
            android:layout_height="53dp"
            android:layout_x="174dp"
            android:layout_y="295dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView19"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_x="20dp"
            android:layout_y="357dp"
            android:text="Work Force"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView22"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_x="20dp"
            android:layout_y="403dp"
            android:text="Subcontractors"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText17"
            android:layout_width="181dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_x="174dp"
            android:layout_y="385dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView23"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_x="20dp"
            android:layout_y="450dp"
            android:text="No. of Person(s)"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText18"
            android:layout_width="128dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_x="174dp"
            android:layout_y="439dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView24"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_x="20dp"
            android:layout_y="500dp"
            android:text="No.of hour(s)"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText19"
            android:layout_width="181dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_x="174dp"
            android:layout_y="488dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView25"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="37dp"
            android:layout_x="20dp"
            android:layout_y="542dp"
            android:text="Work Details"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView26"
            android:layout_width="181dp"
            android:layout_height="54dp"
            android:layout_x="20dp"
            android:layout_y="589dp"
            android:text="Project/Service/Training"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner8"
            android:layout_width="174dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_x="174dp"
            android:layout_y="580dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView27"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="34dp"
            android:layout_x="20dp"
            android:layout_y="650dp"
            android:text="Work Description"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText20"
            android:layout_width="182dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_x="174dp"
            android:layout_y="650dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView28"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="61dp"
            android:layout_x="20dp"
            android:layout_y="706dp"
            android:text="Percentage "
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText21"
            android:layout_width="172dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_x="174dp"
            android:layout_y="706dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView29"
            android:layout_width="101dp"
            android:layout_height="58dp"
            android:layout_x="20dp"
            android:layout_y="760dp"
            android:text="Time In"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText22"
            android:layout_width="176dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_x="174dp"
            android:layout_y="753dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView30"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="79dp"
            android:layout_x="20dp"
            android:layout_y="818dp"
            android:text="Time Out"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText23"
            android:layout_width="176dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_x="174dp"
            android:layout_y="819dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView31"
            android:layout_width="181dp"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:layout_x="20dp"
            android:layout_y="907dp"
            android:text="Project/Service/Training"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner9"
            android:layout_width="174dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_x="174dp"
            android:layout_y="913dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView32"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="37dp"
            android:layout_x="20dp"
            android:layout_y="994dp"
            android:text="Work Description"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText24"
            android:layout_width="182dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_x="174dp"
            android:layout_y="994dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView33"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_x="20dp"
            android:layout_y="1064dp"
            android:text="Percentage "
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText25"
            android:layout_width="172dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_x="174dp"
            android:layout_y="1064dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView34"
            android:layout_width="101dp"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:layout_x="20dp"
            android:layout_y="1143dp"
            android:text="Time In"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText26"
            android:layout_width="176dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_x="174dp"
            android:layout_y="1143dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView35"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:layout_x="20dp"
            android:layout_y="1204dp"
            android:text="Time Out"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText27"
            android:layout_width="176dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_x="174dp"
            android:layout_y="1204dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView36"
            android:layout_width="181dp"
            android:layout_height="67dp"
            android:layout_x="20dp"
            android:layout_y="1302dp"
            android:text="Project/Service/Training"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner13"
            android:layout_width="174dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_x="174dp"
            android:layout_y="1307dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView37"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_x="20dp"
            android:layout_y="1392dp"
            android:text="Work Description"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText28"
            android:layout_width="182dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_x="174dp"
            android:layout_y="1390dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView38"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="98dp"
            android:layout_x="20dp"
            android:layout_y="1458dp"
            android:text="Percentage "
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText29"
            android:layout_width="172dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_x="174dp"
            android:layout_y="1450dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView39"
            android:layout_width="101dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_x="20dp"
            android:layout_y="1524dp"
            android:text="Time In"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText30"
            android:layout_width="176dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_x="174dp"
            android:layout_y="1521dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView40"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="72dp"
            android:layout_x="20dp"
            android:layout_y="1589dp"
            android:text="Time Out"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText31"
            android:layout_width="176dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_x="174dp"
            android:layout_y="1583dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView41"
            android:layout_width="181dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_x="20dp"
            android:layout_y="1668dp"
            android:text="Project/Service/Training"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner14"
            android:layout_width="174dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_x="174dp"
            android:layout_y="1655dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView14"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="57dp"
            android:layout_x="20dp"
            android:layout_y="1746dp"
            android:text="Work Description"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText32"
            android:layout_width="182dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_x="174dp"
            android:layout_y="1746dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView42"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_x="20dp"
            android:layout_y="1825dp"
            android:text="Percentage "
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText33"
            android:layout_width="172dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_x="174dp"
            android:layout_y="1822dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView43"
            android:layout_width="101dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_x="20dp"
            android:layout_y="1890dp"
            android:text="Time In"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText34"
            android:layout_width="172dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_x="174dp"
            android:layout_y="1883dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView44"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="106dp"
            android:layout_x="20dp"
            android:layout_y="1960dp"
            android:text="Time Out"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText35"
            android:layout_width="176dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_x="174dp"
            android:layout_y="1966dp" />
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</ScrollView>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Add fragment to View Pager.

add adapter to view pager in your onCreate() method of activity.

```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Intializing view from xml file
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    // adding adapter to view pager
    VideoViewPagerAdapter adapter = new VideoViewPagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(0, true);
}
```

FragmentPagerAdapter.java

```
public class VideoViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private String[] urls = { "HelloText--", "HellooText--", "HelloText--",
        "HellooText--" };

public VideoViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
    super(fragmentManager);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return urls.length;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    // Create fragment object
    VideoPlayerFragment fragment = new VideoPlayerFragment();

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("STRING_URL", urls[position] + "" + position);

    fragment.setArguments(args);

    return fragment;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return "Page " + (position + 1);
}
}
```

viewpager_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/pager_textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="Helloooo"
    android:textSize="18dp" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

MyFragment.java

```
public class VideoPlayerFragment extends Fragment {

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_layout, container, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.pager_textView);
    String data = getArguments().getString("STRING_URL");
    textView.setText(data);
    return v;
}

}
```

Comment: Nthng wrong with your xml file. But you havn't added any views to scroll view.

Comment: But I have a lot of spinner, textView and EditText. I need to write all ?

Comment: You can any number of views. you will get the scrolling when you views to it. In your xml file, you have added only one linear layout to scrollview. So scrolling won't work with a single view.

Comment: I have edited my post. It just some part of my code. Can you write the example based on my post ? Thanks

Comment: i want to have the pager also

Comment: Can you post your design screen. I will give you the exact designed xml file which u required.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95890/discussion-between-tony-and-saritha-g).